# Laravel : Storage image access in email

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have created `php artisan storage:link` and send images through email but when i try to send images it is not showing on email.

I have stored image path in database. Ex: `/storage/images/user/post/19389aab0edb150ccfcbe0c6bce263409db9be7c.jpg`

when I `dd` the code `asset('/storage/images/user/post/19389aab0edb150ccfcbe0c6bce263409db9be7c.jpg')`

it shows url like

`http://192.168.5.158:8000/storage/images/user/post/19389aab0edb150ccfcbe0c6bce263409db9be7c.jpg`

But it is not working. I have also tried `URL::asset('imagepath')`.Not working.How can i do this ?

Comment: Is this the code in your blade file ?  also, are you using markdown mails to send emails ?

Comment: using `sparkpost` and create `own template`